# Create interval from discrete dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, intervals

I have a function which saves the current status of several objects and writes it in a table, which looks like something like this:

```
ObjectId StatusId Date
1        10       2020-04-04 00:00:00.000
2        10       2020-04-04 00:00:00.000
1        11       2020-04-05 00:00:00.000
2        10       2020-04-05 00:00:00.000
1        10       2020-04-06 00:00:00.000
2        10       2020-04-06 00:00:00.000
```

I would like to make it an interval grouped by ObjectId and StatusId.
So for the above the preferred output would look like this:

```
ObjectId StatusId StartDate               EndDate
1        10       2020-04-04 00:00:00.000 2020-04-04 00:00:00.000
1        11       2020-04-05 00:00:00.000 2020-04-05 00:00:00.000
1        10       2020-04-06 00:00:00.000 2020-04-06 00:00:00.000
2        10       2020-04-04 00:00:00.000 2020-04-06 00:00:00.000
```

Note one object can have the same status on multiple occasions but if it had a different status it needs to be in a separate interval. So simple group by and max(Date) doesn't work in my case.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a form of gaps-and-islands.  For this purpose, the difference of row numbers is probably the simplest method:

```
select objectid, status, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by objectid order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by objectid, status order by date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by objectid, status, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Why this works can be a little cumbersome to explain.  However, if you look at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference is constant for the groups you want to identify.